# Div, placeeholder, autofit available width, content and alignment

Tags: css, html, positioning

Here is an image of my request

[image: Here is an image of my request]

I'm new to CSS and HTML positioning. I've spent three days trying to achieve this disposition to create an inline editor. I want to be able to hold 3 `<div>` or `<span>` or whatever that meet those condition an behavior.

1. Body can be any container.
2. The Pink Div can be anything but will have to contain the 3 other space holder inline
3. The Left Green box is for a variable text length like label
4. The Right Green box is for a variable number of action represented as button or icon.
5. The center green box is for an editor like an input text or multiple field inside a container..

what I did, ha ha ha, exploring every pseudo expert site on css positioning trying framework of all kind and never found a way to achieve this simply, clearly and easy to maintain without hack of any kind....  this is what I did.

Here's my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="../../Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <style>
        div.EditorFrame {
            background-color: lightcyan;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        span.LabelPanel {
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: lightskyblue;
        }

        span.EditorPanel {
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: lightpink;
        }

        span.ButtonPanel {
            display: inline-block;
            text-align: right;
            background-color: lightgreen;

        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function body_onload() {
            //var editor = document.getElementById("txtAddress");
            //var editorcontainer = editor.parentElement;
            //editor.width = editorcontainer.clientWidth;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="body_onload()">
    <div class="EditorFrame">
        <span class="LabelPanel">
            <label for="AddressEditor" id="lblAddressEditor">Enter an address</label>
        </span>
        <span class="EditorPanel">
            <input id="AddressEditor" type="text" /></td>                
        </span>
        <span class="ButtonPanel">
            <button type="submit">Add</button>
            <!--button>Cancel</!--button>-->
        </span>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: We are here to help you, not to do your job. What have you come up with so far?

Comment: SO isn't a place where you make requests for other to write your code for you. It's where you come to get help for solving coding issues that you've already tried to solve on your own.

Comment: <body onload="body_onload()">
    <div class="EditorFrame">
        <span class="LabelPanel">
            <label for="AddressEditor" id="lblAddressEditor">Enter an address</label>
        </span>
        <span class="EditorPanel">
            <input id="AddressEditor" type="text" /></td>                
        </span>
        <span class="ButtonPanel">
            <button type="submit">Add</button>
            <!--button>Cancel</!--button>-->
        </span>
    </div>
</body>

Comment: for the one who say he write code for me... how do you want me to learn if I don't see it.... or express any request????

Comment: @Brainarts I edited you're question. learn how to use SO please.

Comment: @avrahamcool - I try, it's not easy for my first post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, this is not CSS doable...  I Succeed in it with JQuery....

```
EditorPanelWidth = EditorFrame.innerWidth() - LabelPanel.outerWidth() - ButtonPanel.outerWidth();
EditorPanel.outerWidth(EditorPanelWidth);
AdressEditor.width = EditorPanel.innerWidth();
```

There is thing CSS can't do alone... Thank JQuery :)

Answer (score 0):

I think below link will help you.

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: i think he want mask on input field